# Check the characters of a string

Tags: java, string, character

If i have string "h" and it is lets say 10 characters long, how can I check that characters 2 through 10 (ignoring the first character) are all only characters of a certain set, i.e letters A-H or numbers 1-9

Thanks to an answer below I realise I need to use substring and regex, this is what I have tried so far but to no avail;

```
    public boolean isValidCharacters(String h) {
    if (h.substring(2, 10).matches([A-F\d]) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Didn't bother to try?

Comment: Please, add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: see the link on `Substring` [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-substring-method-example/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Regex](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) and [Substring](https://www.javatpoint.com/substring)

For your example it would be something like

```
public boolean isValid(String h) 
{
    return h.substring(1).matches("^[A-H0-9]+$");  
}
```

Comment: This is what I have tried but it doesn't work, think its a syntax error as it just says expected ")" straight after the opening "(" after .matches  

      if (h.substring(2, 10).matches([A-F1-9]) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: 1) You can use h.substring(1), this returns a substring starting at index 1 (inclusive).
2) You need to write the regex as string, like ("^[A-H0-9]+$").

Also you don't need to return true and false, you can just return the whole expression, it will automatically return true if your expression is true and false if it is false.